# Android Extracting data from Firebase data snapshot

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get data from a DataSnapshot from firebase.  I followed the directions in the firebase developer examples.  When I try and pull the data, it comes up as null, although I can see the data when I am running a debugger in Android Studio.  Listed below is the code I am using.

```
    Query mQueryRef = mDatabase.child("users").child(mUserId).child("bullets");
    // This type of listener is not one time, and you need to cancel it to stop
    // receiving updates.
    mQueryRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChild) {
            // This will fire for each matching child node.
            Bullet bullet = snapshot.getValue(Bullet.class);
            String date = bullet.getDate();
            String title = bullet.getTitle();
            mEmailBody + "\n" + title + " " + date;
```

This is the Bullet Class:

```
public class Bullet {

// Bullet basics
private String title;
private String orderDate;
private String date;
private String action;
private String result;
private String impact;

// Default constructor required by Firebase
public Bullet (){

}

//Constructor
public Bullet (String title, String orderDate, String date, String action, String result, String impact) {
    this.title = title;
    this.orderDate = orderDate;
    this.date = date;
    this.action = action;
    this.result = result;
    this.impact = impact;

}

//Getters
public String getTitle() {return title;}
public String getOrderDate() {return orderDate;}
public String getDate() {return date;}
public String getAction() {return action;}
public String getResult() {return result;}
public String getImpact() {return impact;}

//Setters
public void setTitle(String title){
    this.title = title;
}
public void setOrderDate(String orderDate){
    this.orderDate = orderDate;
}
public void setDate(String date){
    this.date = date;
}
public void setAction(String action){
    this.action = action;
}
public void setResult(String result){
    this.result = result;
}
public void setImpact(String impact){
    this.impact = impact;
}
```

}

and this is the json data table from firebase:

```
- appname-1234b
        - users
            - WRQK8Fo3TPUnZyPXYnQ9gHVfFms2
                - bullets
                    - Kfc8jCy5f2bb1aN-o0C
                        - bullet
                          action: "did some stuff"
                          date: "19 Mar 2017"
                          impact: "some stuff was impacted"
                          orderDate: "2017078"
                          result: "a result happened"
                          title: "new one for the date"
                    - KfcMg-7-xp98Kwq-PUR
                        - bullet 
                          action: "did some stuff"
                          date: "19 Mar 2017"
                          impact: "some stuff was impacted"
                          orderDate: "2017078"
                          result: "a result happened"
                          title: "new one for the date"
```

When I run the debugger, as it gets to the line `Bullet bullet = snapshot.getValue(Bullet.class);`
I can see all the data points that look like `Bullet: snapshot {key: Kfc8jCy5f2bb1aN-o0C title:"new one for the date" date:"19 Mar 2017"......}` but when it gets to the next two lines

```
String date = bullet.getDate();
String title = bullet.getTitle();
```

the debugger shows the values as `date = null bullet:3248b` and `title = null bullet:3248b`

I have tried many different ways of extracting the data:

```
String date = snapshot.getValue(Bullet.Class).getDate();
String textBullet = snapshot.getValue(Bullet.Class).toString();
```

but every time it comes up null or has the entirety of the bullet data that is unextractable.

Comment: The json structure is not clear. Can u post a screenshot of how it looks on firebase. I can see Bullet is not a direct child of Bullets and bullet is a child of Kfc8jCy5f2bb1aN-o0C(some id) !

Comment: I can't add a screenshot right now, but "Kfc8jCy5f2bb1aN-o0C" is a key that Firebase automatically assigns to each bullet as it is added from the app.

Comment: added the answer. let me know hw it goes.

Comment: Instead of posting a screenshot, post it as text. You can easily get this by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a child called `bullet` under each push ID, but you're not taking that into account in your listener.

The simplest solution is to skip that `bullet` node in your code:

```
Query mQueryRef = mDatabase.child("users").child(mUserId).child("bullets");
// This type of listener is not one time, and you need to cancel it to stop
// receiving updates.
mQueryRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChild) {
        Bullet bullet = snapshot.child("bullet").getValue(Bullet.class);
        //                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        String date = bullet.getDate();
        String title = bullet.getTitle();
```

But a better solution would be to change your data structure to not have the `bullet` level. If you're not using it in your code, there is not use having it in your database.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  I removed the "bullet" node, and it works perfectly.  Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Your database reference is pointing to bullets, whose value is HashMap and not the Bullet object directly. You need a Hashmap to retrieve the data.

```
private static HashMap<String, Bullet> bullets = new HashMap<>(); 

Query mQueryRef = mDatabase.child("users").child(mUserId).child("bullets");
    // This type of listener is not one time, and you need to cancel it to stop
    // receiving updates.
    mQueryRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange():" + dataSnapshot.toString());

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Bullet bullet = snapshot.getValue(Bullet.class);
                    bullets.put(snapshot.getKey(), bullet);
                }

               //Iterate and Print your bullets hashmap here.
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(bullets)); 
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to read Bullet list.", error.toException());

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot) documentation:

"DataSnapshots are passed to the methods in listeners that you attach with `addValueEventListener(ValueEventListener)`,
`addChildEventListener(ChildEventListener)` , or
`addListenerForSingleValueEvent(ValueEventListener)`".